# I would like the button labels to be able to toggle the properties of text elements in other classes. Is this possible?

Tags: html, css

I would like the button labels (homebutton, aboutmebutton etc.) to be able to toggle the properties of text elements in other classes (skillstext, portfoliotext etc.).

Is this possible?

```css
#aboutmebutton:checked+ul li label aboutmebutton label p.aboutmetext {
 opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="home">
    <input type="checkbox" id="homebutton">
    <label for="homebutton">
                        <a>Home</a>
                        <p class="hometext">This is the Home text.</p>
                    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="aboutmebutton">
    <label for="aboutmebutton">
                        <a>About Me</a>
                        <p class="aboutmetext">This is the About Me text.</p>
                    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="skillsbutton">
    <label for="skillsbutton">
                        <a>Skills</a>
                        <p class="skillstext">This is the Skills text.</p>
                    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="portfoliobutton">
    <label for="portfoliobutton">
                        <a>Portfolio</a>
                        <p class="portfoliotext">This is the Portfolio text.</p>
                    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="contactbutton">
    <label for="contactbutton">
                        <a>Contact</a>
                        <p class="contacttext">This is the Contact text.</p>
                    </label>
  </li>
  </ul
```

Here's an example of CSS I'd like to work, but can't get to:

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS was not correct. The code below works for all buttons.

```css
input:checked + label p {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="home">
    <input type="checkbox" id="homebutton">
    <label for="homebutton">
                        <a>Home</a>
                        <p class="hometext">This is the Home text.</p>
                    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="aboutmebutton">
    <label for="aboutmebutton">
                        <a>About Me</a>
                        <p class="aboutmetext">This is the About Me text.</p>
                    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="skillsbutton">
    <label for="skillsbutton">
                        <a>Skills</a>
                        <p class="skillstext">This is the Skills text.</p>
                    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="portfoliobutton">
    <label for="portfoliobutton">
                        <a>Portfolio</a>
                        <p class="portfoliotext">This is the Portfolio text.</p>
                    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="contactbutton">
    <label for="contactbutton">
                        <a>Contact</a>
                        <p class="contacttext">This is the Contact text.</p>
                    </label>
  </li>
  </ul
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like aboutmebutton to effect another labels text, like contacttext, or skillstext for example.

Comment: @DuncanBennie code is adjusted to work for all labels. If a single input checkbox should hide the text of all other paragraphs, you need javascript.

Comment: Please check: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xyzMQv

I would like the text from one button to dissapear when I select another button.

Comment: Thankyou for your help.

Comment: Ok. I tried hard to not use JS, but thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: @DuncanBennie no problem. Good luck with your project.